# Do I need a "had" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> We watched the sea for a while. Time flew, and before we realized it, we reached harbor.
>
> We watched the sea for a while. Time flew, and before we realized it, we **had** reached harbor.

Which version is the correct one? And why?

Comment: +1 This is an interesting question. IMO, it's not about the tense differences only, but about dialectical differences too.

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether the story-telling at that point had gone past the time they reached the harbour. It almost depends on the next sentence - "We disembarked & continued our journey" would omit the had. "Three days later, upon our return…" feels like the 'had' would be more appropriate. Though I could find valid arguments for the reversal too...

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, the next sentence is something like, "We disembarked with the tourists."

Answer (score 1):

I would say "had reached" is desirable  there because of "before we realized it".

Comment: I'm with you - as I say, I could find arguments for both - depending on 'how far back in time' things were - but I can't argue it through grammatically, that's not my strong point.